# Limit of a sequence with logarithm and square root

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to compute the following limit:

> $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^{\frac{7}{\sqrt{n}}} -1 + 3^{-n}}{(\sqrt{n+7}-\sqrt{n} ) \log((n+1)^3)}$$

which result is $\frac{2}{3}$, but I am not able to prove this. I started by multiplying the denominator by $\sqrt{n+7} + \sqrt{n}$ up and down, so I get $$\frac{(\sqrt{n+7} + \sqrt{n}) (n^{\frac{7}{\sqrt{n}}}-1+3^{-n})}{7\log((n+1)^3)}$$

but I don't know how to move further, to be honest. Could you please tell me how to solve this ?

Comment: Hint: The hardest part is probably the term $n^{\frac{7}{\sqrt{n}}}$.
Notice it can be rewritten as $e^{\frac{7}{\sqrt{n}}\log n}$. Notice for large $n$, $\frac{7}{\sqrt{n}}\log n$ is small and for small $x$, $e^x \sim 1 + x$.

Comment: Thanks, do so I got $(\sqrt{n+7}+\sqrt{n})(n- 3^{-n})$ at the numerator, right? @achillehui

Comment: No, after you get rid of the $\sqrt{n+7}-\sqrt{n}$ in denominator, the numerator is **approximately** $$(\sqrt{n+7} + \sqrt{n})(\frac{7}{\sqrt{n}}\log n +  3^{-n}) \sim 2\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{7}{\sqrt{n}}\log n\right) \sim 14\log n$$ To describe this accurately, you should learn and use the [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Answer (score 2):

Bringing together the ideas in the comments:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^{\frac{7}{\sqrt{n}}} -1 + 3^{-n}}{(\sqrt{n+7}-\sqrt{n} ) \log((n+1)^3)}$$
$$=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(\sqrt{n+7}+\sqrt{n} )(e^{\frac{7\ln n }{\sqrt{n}}} -1 + 3^{-n})}{ 21 \log(n+1)}$$
$$=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2\sqrt{n} (\frac{7\ln n }{\sqrt{n}} + 3^{-n})}{ 21 \log(n+1)}$$
$$=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{14 \ln n + 2\sqrt{n} \, 3^{-n}}{ 21 \log(n+1)}$$
$$=\frac23 \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{ \ln n }{ \log(n+1)} + \frac2{21} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n} \, 3^{-n}}{  \log(n+1)}$$
$$=\frac23 $$